# Which package contains libstdc++ mips cross n32?

Tags: compiling, libraries, cross-compilation

I'm looking for the package that contains libstdc++ for mips cross compile, n32 alignment. Ubuntu 16.04 host.

Comment: Maybe https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/libn32stdc++6-mips-cross

Answer (score 1):

[Here on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B) you can find `libstdc++` packages.

Choose the one that suits you best and select your 16.04 version, and you will get to the page with packages to download.

I think this one is the one you are looking for:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/libn32stdc++6-mips-cross